# Subsidies for low paid / free workers in some EU countries

Tags: european-union, employer

I have heard that that in some EU countries such as Ireland, an employer can receive a €10,000 per year subsidy for simply employing a person who has been unemployed for a certain length of time. Additionally, if you employ low paid or even free workers, you can also be entitled to this subsidy. Is this true?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlueDogRanch I don't see why it belongs there.  It seems to be a very clear question about "is the law actually like this".

Comment: AFAIK there are not "EU laws" related to this; these kind of incentives are linked to national laws of each country and as such they will be different from country to country.

Comment: A valid question can be about the laws of more than one country.  I do not think this is off-topic on law.se, and it should not be closed.

Answer (score 1):

In Ireland there is a scheme called JobsPlus, which is intended to incentivise employers to employ the long-term unemployed. It has two rates, €7,500 and €10,000, depending on the circumstances of the individual unemployed person.

https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/employment/unemployment_and_redundancy/employment_support_schemes/jobsplus.html

Answer (score 0):

Countries anywhere in the world are free to grant subsidies as a means to achieve goals they want to achieve. Getting people back into work who have been unemployed for a long time is both socially good ( a country should try to improve everyone’s well-being) and also financially very good (turning welfare recipients into tax payers is doubly good for a country’s economy).

So yes, it is quite possible that such subsidies exist.

Comment: EU law specifically outlaws subsidies that count as 'state aid', so those countries are not free, for example, to achieve the goal of encouraging home production rather than imports.